# How do I write this method to adhere to the Single Responsibility Principle?

Tags: c#, single-responsibility

I'm writing code that imports values from a CSV file. As part of the import process, I need to write warnings to a log (displayed on screen) when values in the CSV file are invalid.

The method below takes a string value, and a maximum value to check against.

My concern is that the method does two things: it parses a value, and it generates log entries to display. Does this violate the single responsibility principle, and if so, what can be done about it without duplicating the same number-check logic in two methods?

```
private double? GetValidDoubleInMinMaxRange(string importVal, double? maxScore)
{
    if(importVal == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    double val;
    if(double.TryParse(importVal, out val))
    {
        if(val < 0)
        {
            AppInstance.Log.Add(this, LogLevel.Warning, Resources.DataScreenImport_ValueMustBePositive);
            return null;
        }

        if(maxScore.HasValue && val > maxScore.Value)
        {
            AppInstance.Log.Add(this, LogLevel.Warning, Resources.DataScreenImport_ValueGreaterThanMax);
            return null;
        }

        return val;
    }
    else
    {
        AppInstance.Log.Add(this, LogLevel.Warning, Resources.DataScreenImport_ValueWasNotValidInt);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: With a different title, I think this would be a good question for Code Review SE.

Comment: I'd be more worried about passing nulls around

Comment: Not directly answering the question, but your method does not do what it says it does. It says it gets a valid double, but actually it might return a null in case of an error. I fear you are using nulls as error codes, which is a bad idea in .net.

Comment: related (possibly a duplicate): [Style for control flow with validation checks](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/148849/style-for-control-flow-with-validation-checks). Most blatant violation of SRP here seems to be mixing validation checks with the rest of code

Comment: Seems odd to have a warning "ValueMustBePositive".  That sounds more like an error.  I'd probably throw an exception.  On the other hand, to avoid exceptions, one could introduce a notion of a Report as first-class object and add it as a parameter to the function.  That avoids using statics which hamper testability and tightly couples dependencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some case of [primitive obsession](https://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/smells/primitive-obsession) here.

In your case, I would create a dedicated parser `DoubleMinMaxParser` class and have `TryParse(string)` static method that then returns how the parsed string is invalid with valid string in valid case and "undefined" in all others.

Maybe something like :

```
class DoubleMinMaxParser
{
    private readonly double _min;
    private readonly double? _max;

    public enum Result
    {
        Valid,
        TextWasNull,
        InvalidNumber,
        LessThanMin,
        MoreThanMax,
    }

    public DoubleMinMaxParser(double min, double? max)
    {
        _min = min;
        _max = max;
    }

    public Result TryParse(string importVal, out double value)
    {
        if (importVal == null)
        {
            value = 0;
            return Result.TextWasNull;
        }

        if (double.TryParse(importVal, out value))
        {
            if (_min < 0)
            {
                return Result.LessThanMin;
            }

            if (_max.HasValue && value > _max.Value)
            {
                return Result.MoreThanMax;
            }

            return Result.Valid;
        }
        else
        {
            return Result.InvalidNumber;
        }
    }
}

internal class CsvParser
{
    public string GetMessageForMinMaxResult(DoubleMinMaxParser.Result result)
    {
        switch (result)
        {
            case DoubleMinMaxParser.Result.TextWasNull:
                return Resources.DataScreenImport_ValueWasEmpty;
            case DoubleMinMaxParser.Result.InvalidNumber:
                return Resources.DataScreenImport_ValueWasNotValidInt;
            case DoubleMinMaxParser.Result.LessThanMin:
                return Resources.DataScreenImport_ValueMustBePositive;
            case DoubleMinMaxParser.Result.MoreThanMax:
                return Resources.DataScreenImport_ValueGreaterThanMax;
            default:
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("result");
        }
    }

    private double? GetValidDoubleInMinMaxRange(string importVal, DoubleMinMaxParser parser)
    {
        double value;
        DoubleMinMaxParser.Result result = parser.TryParse(importVal, out value);

        if(result == DoubleMinMaxParser.Result.Valid)
        {
            return value;
        }
        else
        {
            AppInstance.Log.Add(this, LogLevel.Warning, GetMessageForMinMaxResult(result));
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```